# Merge of two select queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge these two Select queries into single query. How can i do this?

```
 SELECT link_id, COUNT(*)  FROM Loc  GROUP BY link_id 

     SELECT Slink.[xlink:Show],Loc.[xlink:show],
     Slink.[xlink:actuate],Loc.[xlink:actuate] ,
     href, Sem.SemRoleDescrip
     FROM Sem  JOIN Loc  ON 
     Sem.SemRoleId = Loc.SemRoleId
  JOIN Slink ON Slink.link_id = Loc.link_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### One solution would be to

- add the `COUNT` statement as a subquery
- `(LEFT) JOIN` this subselect with the `SLink` table
- Add the `LinkCount` to the list of selected values.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  Slink.[xlink:Show]
        , Loc.[xlink:show]
        , Slink.[xlink:actuate]
        , Loc.[xlink:actuate] 
        , href
        , Sem.SemRoleDescrip
        , SLinkCount.LinkCount
FROM    Sem  
        JOIN Loc ON Sem.SemRoleId = Loc.SemRoleId
        JOIN Slink ON Slink.link_id = Loc.link_id
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT  link_id, COUNT(*) AS LinkCount 
          FROM    Loc  
          GROUP BY 
                  link_id 
        ) SLinkCount ON SLinkCount.link_id = Slink.link_id
```

**You might want to read up on Subqueries in the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)**

> **12.2.9.8. Subqueries in the FROM Clause**
>
> Subqueries are legal in a `SELECT` statement's `FROM` clause. The actual
>   syntax is:
>
> `SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...`
>
> The `[AS]` name clause is mandatory, because every table in a `FROM`
>   clause must have a name. Any columns in the subquery select list must
>   have unique names.